# How to create files named after lines in a text file under Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, file-management

I have a text file which contains a list of items (one for each line) and I need to create, in a given directory, a file for every entry in the said list; each one of these files should be named with a string in the said list. Also, if possible, after the string contained in the text file, a custom text should be appended to the filenames.

Which commands should I use to do that from the command line? I suppose that `cat`, `grep` and `touch` (and maybe `xargs`?) should be involved in the process, but after a few trials I still can't find the correct syntax.

Can someone enlighten me about this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Say you have `list.txt` like this:

```
file 1
file 2
file 3
```

You can achieve what you want with:

```
while read FILE; do touch "${FILE} some string"; done < list.txt
```

Comment: Why `... < list.txt` rather than `cat list.txt | ...`? Granted the latter spawns a `cat` process which the former doesn't, but it also behaves a lot more predictably, and is more legible besides...

Comment: Redirection is integrated in Bash, there's no need to use `cat` here. If you prefer you can write the redirection before the command: `< list.txt while ...`. Can you elaborate _"but it also behaves a lot more predictably"_?

Comment: ISTR having trouble in the past where `< file` or `< \`command\`` didn't actually produce anything on standard input of the command at which it was aimed, to the point where I gave up trying to get it to work at all -- hence my defaulting to `cat file |` in my answer. That was a while ago, though, and it could just be I didn't know what I was doing; I should probably try it again.

Comment: That said, `< list.txt while read FILE...done` still just looks wrong. I understand that it isn't, but it looks like it should be. :)

Answer (score 9):

So you've got a file `list` which contains:

```
this
that
the-other
```

and you want to create, for each line in that file, a file with the name given on that line. That's pretty easy – if and only if each line consists just of a single word:

```
cat list | xargs touch --
```

(The `--` tells `touch` not to try to parse anything after it as an argument; without it, if you have filenames like `-this`, the leading `-` will confuse touch into thinking 't', 'h', 'i', and 's' are meant as arguments, rather than parts of the literal filename to touch.)

That's the simple case taken care of, but it's not what you asked; if you want the filename to contain some text beyond what's specified on the lines in `list`, things get more complicated; xargs can't do that sort of interpolation. Instead, you'd need something like the following (which requires that your shell is `bash`, as is standard on most systems):

```
for file in `cat list`; do touch -- $file-customtext; done
```

Beware that this still only works if each line consists of a single word only. In this command, `$file` is replaced by the filename specified on a given line in `list`; everything around it is taken literally, so this command with the `list` contents above would create the following files:

```
this-customtext
that-customtext
the-other-customtext
```

You can replace '-customtext' with whatever you like, of course, and you can also have a prefix as well as a suffix; if you instead had `do touch -- some-$file-text`, for example, it'd work just as well, and result in files named `some-this-text` &c.

Now, then, supposing the contents of `list` aren't so simple -- specifically, that they contain spaces, non-word characters, or other things that the shell won't interpret properly. If you ask three people what they'd recommend in this case, you'd likely get five answers; I'm a Perl hacker, so my answer is Perl. Specifically, let's assume a `list` that contains:

```
This is the first line
of three (three?) lines
in the list file.
```

The way I'd do this would be:

```
cat list | perl -ne'chomp; system(qq|touch -- "custom $_ text"|)'
```

Which produces the resulting files:

```
custom This is the first line text
custom of three (three?) lines text
custom in the list file. text
```

The custom text in this case can be whatever you like, spaces and all, so long as it contains neither `"` (which will confuse `touch`) nor `'` (which will confuse `perl`); in the Perl command, `$_` represents the contents of a given line from `list`, and custom text belongs either before or after it, but within the double quotes. (Custom text outside the double quotes will be regarded by `touch` as a separate filename, which will be literally created unless it contains something that'll cause `touch` to error out.)

Comment: We're almost there! The only problem is that the entries in my textfile are not single words, but strings containing multiple words. I.e. I could have an entry named `This is the first entry (2001)` and the command you suggested gives me as output `This-customtext`, `is-customtext`, `the-customtext`, `first-customtext` and so on. But I need instead a file named `This is the first entry (2001)-customtext`

Comment: Well, that complicates matters nicely! Let me see what I can come up with...

Comment: I tried enclosing each entry in the text file with `"`, `'` or `\`` but it didn't solved anything at all.

Comment: Nope! Apparently when you `for` across lines in `bash`, it takes any whitespace as a line separator, instead of just `\n`. I knew `bash` was weird and picky, but...In any case, I've updated the answer to handle this case by means of a little command-line Perl.

Comment: Also, just FYI, enclosing a string in backticks (`\``), most places where you can do that, will cause the string to be taken as a command whose results are interpolated in its place, as in the `for` construct in my answer.

Comment: Please read: [Why you shouldn't read lines with for](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) – there's no need for `perl` workarounds or `cat`ing really, you just need to use a `while read` construct instead. Bash isn't being picky, it just treats [whitespace as an argument separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator).

Comment: @slhck Thanks! (Perl is almost always the first tool I reach for in any case, so that's not so much a workaround for me, but I appreciate the additional information regarding the disaster that is Bash syntax.)

Comment: Bash takes a while getting used to, but there's often a standard way to do things which you'll have to learn once and then apply everywhere :) The [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) covers almost any case though.

Comment: @Aaron Miller: Superb, thank you, it worked perfectly! As a workaround, I also found that substituting white spaces with underscores in the source file, then processing the output files with a tool like `krename` to turn back again underscores to white spaces can be a trickier but nonetheless working solution.

Comment: @Sekhemty I would really recommend against using such a workaround. Bash can treat files with spaces in their name just fine, you just have to use the proper commands (see cYrus' answer below). Many problems people have with Bash stem from "wrong" commands they found like `for` loops to iterate on files. Those work fine for many cases but break unexpectedly for others.

Comment: @slhck: Interesting, and excuse my inexperience, but without using perl, what would have been a correct bash command sequence to perform what I need?  I tried using cyrus' solution but I still got a file for every word rather than for every line. I ask for the sake of learning of course.

Comment: @slhck I'd argue rather strenuously that the problem here is with Bash, rather than with its user. Either Bash shouldn't produce this kind of gotcha, or it should leave programming tasks to programming languages.

Comment: @Sekhemty Did you see cYrus' answer? `while read file; do touch "${file}"; done < input.txt` basically does it.

Comment: @Sekhemty See cYrus's answer and the comments to it for more on that point. That said, I'd recommend against learning Bash in any more detail than is necessary for self-defense; if you want to do something complex enough to require programming, you're much better off doing so in a real programming language.

Comment: @slhck: Yes, I've seen it and tried using it, but I got a file for every word in a line rather than a file for every line; and the additional custom text is appended just on the last word of every line.

Comment: @Sekhemty Check again; the double quotes around the argument to `touch`, which were edited into the answer some time after it was originally posted, prevent that from happening.

Comment: Ok, I refreshed the page and the double quotes on the string now made the command work as intended; I wasn't aware that the answer was edited, now unfortunately I can't accept both answers :)